# SQL - Shortcut for long WHEN condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need to write a long WHEN statement in a SQL query - is there a shortcut way of writing this ?

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN col1 = 0 AND col2 = 0 AND col3 = 0 AND col4 = 0 AND col5 = 0 AND col6 = 0  AND col7 = 0 AND (more...) AND col20 = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS is_zero
  FROM some_table;
```

Comment: Assuming your columns hold integer values then using arithmetic like this: `when (col1+col2+col3 ... +col20) = 0 then ...` might save you some space, but in the end there's no easy way of getting around having to list the columns.

Comment: `(col1,col2,...col20) = (0,0,...0)` or for the whole row: `some_table = (0,...0)`

Comment: `(col1 = 0 AND col2 = 0 AND col3 = 0 AND col4 = 0 AND col5 = 0 AND col6 = 0  AND col7 = 0 ... AND col20 = 0 ) AS is_zero` does the same, but results in a boolean instead of an int.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `AND` condition and so NO, there is no shortcut present for this. Would it have been `OR` condition then you could have done like

```
CASE WHEN 0 in (col1,col2,col3,col4,...,coln)
```

Comment: Reverse the CASE and apply DeMorgan's Law and you'll have your ORs.